# Which bookmark sync technology will be used in 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.04, firefox, sync

I assume 11.04 is going to use Firefox 4, is Ubuntu going to keep using Ubuntu One sync or are they going to change over to the Firefox Sync built into 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will continue to use and expand the bindwood plugin we currently have.

Comment: I think firefox sync is a better choice (it think bookmarks, history, passwords...), is still open source, works very well...

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 11.04 will probably ship with Firefox 4, which will probably come with its own built-in sync feature (the feature is and was available as an extension in 10.10 and before). Other browsers in 11.04 may also ship with their own built-in sync feature. Ubuntu One will continue to offer its bookmark sync tech independently of them, and users will continue to be able to choose the one that better suits their needs.